# Writing a function List to a tuple

Tags: list, haskell, types, tuples

how to write a function from list to a tuple

i have taken the string to a tuple. but i need to send it to a tuple.

can someone help me

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a list to a tuple in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921345/how-do-i-convert-a-list-to-a-tuple-in-haskell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't convert an arbitrarily long list to a tuple because tuples of different lengths are considered as distinct types. But you can have:

```
listToTuple2 :: [a] -> (a, a)
listToTuple3 :: [a] -> (a, a, a)
listToTuple4 :: [a] -> (a, a, a, a)
listToTuple5 :: [a] -> (a, a, a, a, a)
```

etc.

See also http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell#Convert_the_first_n_elements_of_a_list_to_a_tuple.

Comment: thanks a lot. i found a solution. but have some small clarification to do


listtotuple :: [String] -> (String,String,String)
listtotuple [] = error "Empty List"
listtotuple (a:b:c:d) = (a,b,c)

i tried just putting (a:b:c) only but its not working. then i put another one . then it work. can someone explain the reason for that

Comment: @Pradeep: `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. The RHS of the cons operator must be a list. And you can just use pattern matching `listtotuple [a,b,c] = (a,b,c)`.

Comment: `[a,b,c]` is equivalent to `(a:b:c:[])`, and will match a list of exactly three elements.  To match a list of three or more (and bind names to the first three), you can use `(a:b:c:d)` or, since in this case you don't need to refer to the rest of the list as `d`, `(a:b:c:_)`.  Note the difference between `[]` matching the empty list, and `_` or `d` matching any list.