# How can I convert an array to a tuple?

Tags: arrays, swift, type-conversion, tuples

I just want to convert an array into a tuple in Swift; something like the following:

```
>>> myArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> mytuple = tuple(myArray)
>>> mytuple
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

What's the easiest way of doing that?

(I only started learning Swift today, so I am very, very new).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't do this because the size of a tuple is part of its type, and this isn't true for an array. If you know the array's length, you can just do `let myTuple = (myArray[0], myArray[1], ...)`. Or you can build your architecture around tuples from the beginning. What are you trying to do?

This is a common problem which occurs in lots of other languages. See [How do I convert a list to a tuple in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921345/how-do-i-convert-a-list-to-a-tuple-in-haskell)

Comment: Not trying to build anything, just curious. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 26):

It's actually quite possible, if you are willing to do some low level magic. I don't think it works if the tuple has a **collection type**, though. This is mainly for interacting with C libraries.

```
typealias TupleType = (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)

var array = [2, 3, 4] as [UInt8]
var tuple = UnsafeMutablePointer<StepsType>(malloc(UInt(sizeof(TupleType))))
memcpy(tuple, array, UInt(array.count))
```

More of this stuff can be found here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84476/array-to-tuple-in-swift/84528#84528

---

Because 70% of us are highly visual beings:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

if what you want to do is extract multiple value from array at the same time, maybe 
the following code could help you

```swift
extension Array {
    func splat() -> (Element,Element) {
        return (self[0],self[1])
    }

    func splat() -> (Element,Element,Element) {
        return (self[0],self[1],self[2])
    }

    func splat() -> (Element,Element,Element,Element) {
        return (self[0],self[1],self[2],self[3])
    }

    func splat() -> (Element,Element,Element,Element,Element) {
        return (self[0],self[1],self[2],self[3],self[4])
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this

```swift
  let (first,_,third) = ( 0..<20 ).map { $0 }.splat()
```

you can even write a codegen to generate the extension code

Answer (score 2):

Scared of unsafe pointers? Or need support for tuples with different types inside?

It can also be done like this:

```
public extension Array {

    public var tuple: Any? {
        switch count {
        case 0:
            return ()
        case 1:
            return (self[0])
        case 2:
            return (self[0], self[1])
        case 3:
            return (self[0], self[1], self[2])
        case 4:
            return (self[0], self[1], self[2], self[3])
        case 5:
            return (self[0], self[1], self[2], self[3], self[4])
        default:
            return nil
     }
 }
```

Because typing this out can be a little error prone, it's a good idea to [write tests](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/mennolovink/ArrayPlusTuple/blob/develop/fastlane/test_output/report.html) for this that make sure the right tuple is returned.

I've used this approach in [ArrayPlusTuple](https://github.com/mennolovink/ArrayPlusTuple).

So instead of writing this functionality yourself you could just add `pod 'ArrayPlusTuple'` to your pod file and get this tested functionality for free.

Answer (score 2):

This my universal solution for copy array data to tuple. The only problem that I could not solve is to check the type of the element in the tuple and the element from the array.

```
/// Unsafe copy array to tuple
func unsafeCopyToTuple<ElementType, Tuple>(array: inout Array<ElementType>, to tuple: inout Tuple) {
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &tuple) { pointer in
        let bound = pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: ElementType.self, capacity: array.count) { $0 }
        array.enumerated().forEach { (bound + $0.offset).pointee = $0.element }
    }
}
```