# How to convert a tuple of Eithers to a list of Eithers?

Tags: haskell

I got a tuple with Either values in it,

```
(Left "Error1", Right 1, Left "Error2", Right 2)
```

How can i convert this to

```
[Left "Error1", Right 1, Left "Error2", Right 2]
```

?

Since I want to do lefts on the list and get all Left values from

```
[Left "Error1", Right 1, Left "Error2", Right 2]
```

I have something like this with 38 values in the tuple, `(Left "Error1", Right 1, Left "Error2", Right "NameString")` is it possible to get only the left values from the tuple?

Comment: Is the tuple always a 4-tuple?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no

Answer (score 8):

This question has nothing to do with `Either` – you could as well ask how to convert a tuple of characters into a list of characters.

The answer is: there is no standard method for doing this, but you can just write a lambda / custom function

```
    \(a,b,c,d) -> [a,b,c,d]
```

You should ask yourself the question why you have such a tuple in the first place. Big-ish homogeneous tuples seem fishy; probably you should instead built a list right where it comes from instead.

Answer (score 5):

Bonus answer: if you were using *lens*, you could do it with the `each` traversal. 
`each` can handle tuples of various sizes because it relies on an `Each` class that has instances for them.

```
GHCi> import Control.Lens
GHCi> toListOf each (Left "Error1", Right 1, Left "Error2", Right 2)
[Left "Error1",Right 1,Left "Error2",Right 2]
```

Yet another possibility would be relying on `Foldable` instances for homogeneous tuples provided by the [*tuples-homogenous-h98*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuples-homogenous-h98-0.1.1.0/docs/Data-Tuple-Homogenous.html) package.

```
GHCi> import Data.Foldable
GHCi> import Data.Tuple.Homogenous
GHCi> toList (Tuple4 (Left "Error1", Right 1, Left "Error2", Right 2))
[Left "Error1",Right 1,Left "Error2",Right 2]
```

This digression aside, I subscribe to [leftaroundabout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50929526/2751851).

Comment: what if i got something like this (Left "Error1", Right 1, Left "Error2", Right "NameString")

Comment: @SamuelD'costa Then you don't have an homogeneous tuple, and so you can't put all its elements in a list (as they have different types) unless you change them into something else.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a tuple with exactly four values in it to a list with exactly four values in it like:

```
f :: (a, a, a, a) -> [a]
f (a1, a2, a3, a4) = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
```

You can then proceed to use `lefts :: [Either a b] -> [a]` from [Data.Either](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:lefts).

But as the answer to the opposite question, [How do I convert a list to a tuple in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921345/how-do-i-convert-a-list-to-a-tuple-in-haskell), suggests, *in a general way, you can't*. Generally when you have a specific number of elements (a tuple), you should want to know what to do with them specifically.